# Using Collection sort for ArrayList

Tags: arrays, collections, generic-collections

```
class UnfairContainer<T> implements Comparable<UnfairContainer>
{    
    private ArrayList<T> array = new ArrayList<T>();

    public void sort()
    {
        Collections.sort(array);
    }

    public int compareTo(UnfairContainer o)
    {

    }
}
```

So i have my class that implements comparable but when i try to create the sort method that calls Collections.sort(), it gives me an error that says i can't call collection sort with an ArrayList . Can anyone help? and help me with my compareTo method, i'm stuck on how i'm suppose to compare each element within my ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the list is not guaranteed to be sort-able. This is because with your current setup, `T` could be anything- including a class that does not implement `Comparable` and hence cannot be sorted by `Collections`. The type signature of `Collections.sort()` reflects this:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list);
```

To fix this, you need to put an upper bound on T to ensure that it is sort-able:

```
class UnfairContainer<T extends Comparable<T> > 
        implements Comparable<UnfairContainer<T> >
{

...
```

The `T extends Comparable<T>` means that T must be a class that implements Comparable. This lets Collections know that the ArrayList can be sorted, and everything works.

For more information, please refer to the [java trail on bounded wildcards in generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html)